# How java converts int to boolean

Tags: java, casting, int, boolean

When i convert:

```
int B=1;
boolean A=B;
```

**It gives error: Incompatible types, which is true**

But when I write this code:

```
int C=0;
boolean A=C==1;
```

**it gives false 
while if I change value of C to 1 it gives true.
I don't understand how compiler is doing it.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int C=0;
boolean A=C==1;
```

The compiler first gives C a zero.

```
Variable : C
Value    : 0
```

Now The Assignment statement,

We know that the assignment statement evaluates the right part first and the gives it to the left.

The right part `==> C == 1`
Here, This is an expression which evaluates to `true` or `false`. In this case it is false as `c is 0.`

So the R.H.S is false.

Now this gets assigned to the L.H.S which is A.

```
A = ( C == 1 ) ==> A = false
```

As `A` is a boolean this is a right statement

Answer (score 4):

`C==1` is an expression whose result is `boolean` (it's the comparison operator). It returns `true` if `C` equals to 1 and `false` otherwise.

Therefore `boolean A=C==1;` is a valid assignment of a `boolean` value to a `boolean` variable.

Answer (score 2):

It checks `c==1` first and result getting assigned to `A`.

as `C` is not 1 so expression value is resulting to false which is assigned to `A`